# Symfony2 FosRestBundle root api url

Tags: api, symfony, namespaces, fosrestbundle

I've been looking at the FOS-Rest-Bundle documentation in order to develop an API of mine. The problem is that I would like the API to be under api/ and there doesn't seem to be any option to achieve this.

Is there a way? how would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a prefix in your routing.
See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#prefixing-imported-routes

For example :

```
api_rest:
    type: rest
    prefix: /api
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/rest_routes.yml"
```